# Post Does Not Return 200 OK in Liberator Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp, clojurescript, ring, liberator

I want my POST resource to return **200** OK so I can use :**handle-ok** but resource returns **201** Created.

I use my resource for the login operation. **:handle-ok** does not work!

Here is the **example** code:

```
(POST "/login" []
             (resource :allowed-methods [:post]
                       :available-media-types resource-util/avaliable-media-types
                       :known-content-type? #(resource-util/check-content-type % resource-util/avaliable-media-types)
                       :malformed? #(resource-util/parse-json % ::data)
                       :post! (fn [ctx]
                                {:my-data "oki"})
                       :handle-ok (fn [ctx]
                                    {:ok? true})))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `:new? false :respond-with-entity? true` to your resource definition. Check out more details in the [decision graph](https://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/assets/img/decision-graph.svg). You should also return a value that will be the  body of the response (as you want to return HTTP 200, if you have no value to be returned HTTP 204 is more appropriate).

Comment: Thank you.What is respond with entity?

Comment: Take a look at [liberator decisions](https://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/decisions.html). `:respond-with-entity` means that the modified/deleted resource entity should be returned in the response (e.g. `POST /user` as a result will return the created user entity in the response body).